# "live on government aid" or "live off government aid"?

Tags: collocation

Is there a difference in meaning between "live on government aid" and "live off government aid"? Are both correct written forms?

Comment: If there's a difference, I think it's very slight.

Comment: The proportion of people who [*live **off** state benefits*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live+off+state+benefits%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (about 2 in 5, compared to those who [*live **on** state benefits*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live+on+state+benefits%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)) is apparently twice as great those who say they [*live **off** my pension*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live+off+my+pension%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) rather than ***on** it*. But it's not really significant to most people.

Comment: I assume that to "live off something" implies that you "live off of" it, which should be the same as to "live on" it, so I'm thinking there is no difference.  I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't have a source.